# What secure disk format allows me to plug in and access in both Raspberry Pi and laptop (Mac OSX, Windows 8)?

Tags: hard-drive, password

I want to create a file backup server using the Raspberry Pi. I would like the hard drive to be connected to the device and be accessed by connecting wirelessly via the Raspberry Pi. At the same time, I would like to be able to disconnect the hard drive from the Raspberry Pi and connect it directly into my laptop's USB port or any other computer running Mac OS X and Windows 7/8 in case if I want to access it quickly. How can I make sure that I can do both of those things and make sure that my drive is password protected?

I was thinking about something like the exFAT format but I'm not sure what to do to make it secure and password protected and accessible to my devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

You should use Ext4 if you want reliable fully featured storage when connected to the Pi, but neither OS X or Windows has support for Ext4 (there is 3rd party support).

No FAT system has support for the attributes required for backup, and security.

You could try NTFS (with loss of support for journalling), but OS X only has read support.

I am not sure about Linux support for HFS+, but Windows won't even see these.